# How can I get the same results in Python is it in the following MATLAB code? how to change this code into Python?

Tags: python, matlab

In short how can I change this 1 line code `reshape((b-c)/d,1,[])`  into python?

```
>> a=1:20;
>> b=reshape(a,4,5)

b =

     1     5     9    13    17
     2     6    10    14    18
     3     7    11    15    19
     4     8    12    16    20

>> c=-3;
>> d=2;
>> reshape((b-c)/d,1,[])

ans =

  Columns 1 through 17

    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000    8.5000    9.0000    9.5000   10.0000

  Columns 18 through 20

   10.5000   11.0000   11.5000
```

Comment: Can you explain in your own words what this line is supposed to do, and what has been the difficulty when you tried to write the equivalent code in Python?

Comment: Since b is an array c and d are integers and I do not understand the other two 1 and [ ]. I am working on a project what I am doing just to change the whole code into python.

Comment: So you need to first understand what the Matlab code does before you can attempt to write it in Python.

Comment: If I understand why I would post it here? I just run the code which is clear what it is doing? how else do you need to understand? I already run and the results are infront of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,21)
b = a.reshape(5,4)

c = -3
d = 2
ans = ((b-c)/d).flatten()

# array([ 2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,  5.5,  6. ,  6.5,  7. ,
#         7.5,  8. ,  8.5,  9. ,  9.5, 10. , 10.5, 11. , 11.5])
```

If you're set on `b` in the shape as shown in your question, you'll need to transpose twice (which isn't necessary otherwise). I.e.:

```
a = np.arange(1,21)
b = a.reshape(5,4).transpose()

array([[ 1,  5,  9, 13, 17],
       [ 2,  6, 10, 14, 18],
       [ 3,  7, 11, 15, 19],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16, 20]])

c = -3
d = 2
ans = ((b-c)/d).transpose().flatten()

# array([ 2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,  5.5,  6. ,  6.5,  7. ,
#         7.5,  8. ,  8.5,  9. ,  9.5, 10. , 10.5, 11. , 11.5])
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `transpose` twice (or once, after the edit)? Can't you just use `ans = (a-c)/d`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: sorry for the confusion, was copy/pasting the wrong bit. It's not necessary, of course, but I can imagine that the shape of `b` matters for the OP.